# Option Button - One per row - 2016 Properties (group renaming)

Tags: javascript, excel, radio-button

I have a grid of 5 columns and 5 rows of Option buttons. I am trying to have it so each row has one active button, to no avail.

What I have tried thus far; 
1. Selected each radio button (in a row) > Group using option in ribbon
2. Select each radio button (in a row) > Forms Group function > Group using option in the ribbon
3. Searched online for the solution and I am finding them saying that I need to change the Option Button name through properties, I have looked and found this, but there is no option to change the name in the dialog box, I am thinking this is because I am using excel 2016. 
4. I have seen some macro and javascripts throughout the internet that will do these functions but I do not have much experience to understand it enough to execute.

Any help or assistance you can provide will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, may i ask you, What have you tried? show us your code, and please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you using the option buttons from "Form Controls" or from "ActiveX Controls" ? Grouping option buttons works differently depending which buttons you are using.

Comment: I have not used any coding at this time as it states in my questions I am not familiar with such things such as macros and javascript.

Comment: I am using the option button from the activeX Controls